# Serialized Array Separation in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, serialization

I am working on API which provides serialized array of product. I'm using PHP. I want to seperate each array and use elements of the arrays to create lists in HTML. I don't know how to get each element from the array to make a list. Will you help me?

```
<?php
$url="http://www.seoclerks.com/api?type=inlinead&s=&aff=119253&by=&mp=&p=&c=0&ul=4&am=40&ins=0&g=0&sub=0&os=0&sp=0&oby=&oh=ASC&f=serialized";
$feed=file_get_contents($url);
$data=unserialize($feed);
print_r($data);
echo $data->
?>
```

The above code produces something o/p like below

```
Array ( [13] => Array ( [id] => 504 [prefix] => will [title] => send you 372 highly spinned comments for Scrapebox [description] => Hey there Download my list of Scrapebox comments.They are highly spun and they are really nice. [positive_ratings] => 0 [negative_ratings] => 0 [service_url] => http://a.seoclerks.com/linkin/119253/Other/504/send-you-372-highly-spinned-comments-for-Scrapebox [order_url] => http://a.seoclerks.com/linkin/119253/order?id=504 [display_title] => send you 372 highly spinned comments for Scrapebox for $5 [price] => 5 [tags] => scrapebox comments list [days] => 1 [views] => 1320 [image] => https://www.seoclerks.com/pics/504-1.png [image_small] => https://www.seoclerks.com/pics/t2/504-1.png [image_med] => https://www.seoclerks.com/pics/t/504-1.png [subscription] => 0 [instant_download] => 1 [total_orders] => 0 [last_update] => 1322071772 [total_bookmarks] => 0 [combined_ratings] => 0 [guarantee] => 0 [on_sale] => 0 [staff_certified] => 0 [seller_username] => JaanPorkon [seller_userlevel] => 4 [seller_bio] => I'm a professional internet marketer, programmer and a designer. I have been doing it around
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After unserializing data. You just need to loop through it and use it within HTML tags according to your design. You can find list of all supported keys for returned array from [SEOClerks's API Page](https://www.seoclerk.com/api/page/serviceads)

```
<?php
$url="http://www.seoclerks.com/api?type=inlinead&s=&aff=119253&by=&mp=&p=&c=0&ul=4&am=40&ins=0&g=0&sub=0&os=0&sp=0&oby=&oh=ASC&f=serialized";
$feed=file_get_contents($url);
$data=unserialize($feed);
foreach($data as $item){ ?>
       <div id="id-<?php echo $item['id'];?>" > 
         <h1><?php echo $item['title'];?></h1>
         <p><?php echo $item['descripition']; ?></p>
       </div>
<?php   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an iterator like `foreach`

```
foreach($data as $datum){ 

echo $datum['id'];
echo $datum['prefix'];

// or : 

    } ?> 

<div id="id-<?=$datum['id']?>" > 
     <h1><?=$datum['title']?> </h1>
 <!-- etc --> 
</div>
```